# When appending two shapefiles in ArcMap 10.2 values in attribute table become distorted

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-table, append

I have appended two point shapefiles using [append](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdsvfKzKrXAhWQ5qQKHbI-DcQQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpro.arcgis.com%2Fen%2Fpro-app%2Ftool-reference%2Fdata-management%2Fappend.htm&usg=AOvVaw3pQkMdpOkzeZ_zSkLOZlYT) tool in Arcmap saved in C:drive (I tried in geodatabase before and it did not work). After successfully obtaining new appended shapefile, which seems incomplete,  I then use 'feature to feature class' obtaining a complete attribute table but with all the string values (ID codes, coordinates, geographic references) moved/unordered in different columns with incorrect column title.

What can I do to correct this and obtain a complete/correct appended shapefile?

Comment: When trying to append when shapefiles are in geodatabase I get the error 000224: cannot insert features.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to [append](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm) two or more feature classes in Arcmap with different fields name or type, change schema type to **No_Test**.If you need you can select fields manually in in **Field Map**.
to take some fields out:

- Go to **Layer properties** then select **Fields** tab. uncheck the fields

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The field names and types are exactly the same, as far as I am aware. I even took some fields out (exaclty the same ones) from both shapefiles to reduce the number of columns.

Comment: Thank you again. I have noticed that the id code fild is 'Long' in one shapefile and 'Text' in another but even after staring editing mode it will not let me change it. How can I edit this?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @ElisaPineda. I think the second question is not about append, so please start a new question about editing problem. Thanks